# How to revert changes made to Windows 10 by "Destroy Windows Spying" (DWS_Lite.exe)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy, cortana

I've found a tool that claimed is able to ban Microsoft Windows 10 from keylogging, Anonymous telemetry, and Spying on my personal information. It's called [Destroy Windows Spying](https://github.com/Nummer/Destroy-Windows-10-Spying/releases) *(DWS_Lite.exe)*. After running this freeware, I noticed undesired changes to my computer, including:

- Disabled Cortana
- Disabled Windows Defender
- Disabled Windows Web Search
- Disabled Password Reveal Button
- Disabled Location Services

And many others I can't recall. I tried registry tweaks available online to enable Cortana, but it didn't help. I see a gray Cortana switch button, showing the message:

*"Cortana is disabled by company policy"*

[image]

How to fix Cortana? Or if possible, totally revert changes made to my system?

Comment: Note that turning on Cortana will resume sending Cortana searches to Microsoft.

Comment: You can get the registry changes made by DWS in this GitHub source code. Link:: [DWS/MainDwsForm.cs](https://github.com/Nummer/Destroy-Windows-10-Spying/blob/master/DWS/MainDwsForm.cs).

Comment: @Biswa Thank you for the tip. I just wanted to make something easily applicable by a novice user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Destroy Windows Spying Neutralizer (DWS_Neutralizer.cmd)

After thorough research, I've found a list of changes made by [DWS](http://dws.wzor.net/):

**Delete Keylogger and Telemetry:**

- Disables and deletes some of Diagnostics and Windows Media push services.
- Disables *Cortana* from registry, **by Computer Policy**.
- Disables *Windows Telemetry* from registry.
- Disables *Diagnostics* from registry.
- Disables *Inclusion of MRT in Windows Update* from registry.

**Add spy domains in hosts file, and block in Windows Firewall:**

- Blocks *Microsoft telemetry* URLs from hosts file.
- Blocks *Microsoft telemetry* IP ranges from firewall.
- Blocks *Microsoft telemetry* IP ranges from routing table.

**Disable Private Settings:**

- Disbales *Cortana* from registry, **by User Policy**.
- Disables *Camera on LockScreen* from registry.
- Disables *Biometrics* from registry.
- Disables *Bing Search* from registry.
- Disables *Web Search* from registry.
- Disables *Password Reveal Button* from registry.
- Disables *Sensors* from registry.
- Disables *Location Services* from registry.

**Disable Windows Defender:**

- Disables *Windows Defender* from registry.
- Disables *Automatic Malware Sample Submission* from registry.
- Disables *Malware Reporting* from registry.
- Disables *Smart Screen Filter* from registry.

**Set Default Windows Photo Viewer:**

- Self-descriptive I guess!

**Disable Spy Tasks:**

- Disables *Diagnostics* from task scheduler.
- Disables *Media Center Discovery* from task scheduler.
- Disables *Office Telemetry* from task scheduler.
- Disables *Customer Experince* from task scheduler.
- Disables *WinSAT Maintenance* from task scheduler.

This script reverts all the changes to their default settings.

*Note: It doesn't reinstall removed metro apps!*

**Disclaimer:** *This method is tested and working. However, there's a chance that I didn't mentioned all the changes, and maybe I missed some registry keys. Please be warned that it reverts affected settings to Out-of-Box state, so if you changed some of those, you may need to re-enable/configure them.* **!Do it at your ownrisk!**

Download as script:
[DWS_Neutralizer.cmd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetwOrchestration/DWS_Neutralizer/master/DWS_Neutralizer.cmd) (*Note: Run as admin*)

Download as archive:
[DWS_Neutralizer.zip](https://github.com/NetwOrchestration/DWS_Neutralizer/raw/master/DWS_Neutralizer.zip) (*Note: Extract, then run as admin*)

**Based on**: *DWS (Final)* **Last Updated:** *2015-12-29*

Comment: Bless you, this fixed some problems I was having and I didn't have to reinstall Windows. That'll teach me to run some program some guy made when I'm feeling paranoid about legitimate operating system features.